# replace columns with "0" and "1"

Tags: r

this is my data frame:
[image]

i want to replace columns Price with number with "1" and "0" for NA, and i want my output like this:

```
Time                      Price
2018-03-05 09:00:00         1
2018-03-05 09:00:00         1
2018-03-05 09:00:00         1
2018-03-05 09:00:00         1
.                           .
.                           .
2018-03-05 09:02:00         0
```

Comment: Could you share your data with `dput(head(df,12))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `is.na()` and convert its logical output to a numeric via `as.integer`, i.e.

```
df$Price <- as.integer(!is.na(df$Price))
```

Comment: Or just `+!(is.na(df$Price))`

Comment: @utubun I 'd rather avoid code golfing to that extend as it becomes really unreadable

Comment: yeas, agreed. But the possibility still exists)

Comment: @utubun Oh there are a few ways...another is to do `(!is.na(df$Price)) * 1`...

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `ifelse` from base R for the replacement task, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df, Price <- ifelse(is.na(Price),0,1))
```

- or just `1 - is.na()` to generate sequence with `1` and `0`

```
df <- within(df, Price <- 1 - is.na(Price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse()`

```
df$Price <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Price), 1, 0)
```